# Problems reading numbers in scientific format in C using fscanf()

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, scanf

I have multiple textfiles with data as follows:

```
    0.000000E+0 0.000000E+0
    1.800000E-1 0.000000E+0
    4.200000E-1 0.000000E+0
    6.950000E-1 0.000000E+0
    9.450000E-1 0.000000E+0
    1.225000E+0 0.000000E+0
```

which was generated by a test instrument. The two columns of data are separated by the tab character. I am trying to read this data file into a program for further processing. The code which i wrote is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float **make_array(int size); //function to make 2D array

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *infile;
        infile=fopen(argv[1], "r");

//count number of lines in file
        char c;
        int i=0, numlines=0;
        while((c=fgetc(infile))!=EOF)
                if(c == '\n') numlines++;

        printf("numlines: %d\n", numlines);

        float **entry = make_array(numlines);

//read inputfile
        for(i=0; i< numlines; i++)
                fscanf(infile, " %G\t%G", &entry[0][i], &entry[1][i]);
//verify read values
        printf("\n");
        for(i=0; i<numlines; i++)
                printf("%E\t%E\n", entry[0][i], entry[1][i]);

//clean up before exiting
        free(entry[0]);
        free(entry[1]);
        free(entry);
        fclose(infile);
return 0;
}


//create a 2D array of 2 by {size}
float **make_array(int size){
        int i;
        float **entry = malloc(2*sizeof(float *));
        if(entry==NULL) exit(1);
        entry[0] = malloc(size*sizeof(float *));
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) entry[0][i] == 0.0;
        entry[1] = malloc(size*sizeof(float *));
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) entry[1][i] == 0.0;

return entry;
}
```

When i compile and run the program, it prints out the number of lines in the file correctly but the printf statement to verify the data read into the array `entry` just prints out all zeros, like below:

```
numlines: 252

0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00
```

I tried different format specifiers for `fscanf` like `%g,%e,%f,%G etc` but they all give the same result.  Also, i am using Ubuntu 12.04 with GCC 4.6. Any pointers to what's wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Khadija.

Comment: Did you debug it? Why using "%G\t%G" are you sure there is a `\t` character in the middle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial loop:

```
while((c=fgetc(infile))!=EOF)
    if(c == '\n') numlines++;
```

read the entire input file (to determine the size of the array). Once you've done that, your calls to `fscanf` all fail because you're already at the end of the file.

Assuming the input file is seekable (which it should be if it's a disk file), you can use `rewind()` or `fseek()` to go back to the beginning and read it again.

BTW, your use of `%G` and `%E` format specifiers is valid, but `%g` and `%e` are more common (and should work in exactly the same way).

And you really should check the value of `argc` before referring to `argv[1]`; the program will likely blow up if invoked with no command-line arguments. You should also check whether `fopen()` succeeded, and that `fscanf()` returned 2 to indicate that it successfully read two data items.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The program reads data correctly now. Thank you also for the suggestions on checking for program arguments. I have added that in.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is in:

```
while((c=fgetc(infile))!=EOF)
            if(c == '\n') numlines++;
```

After you execute that while loop, your FILE* is pointing at EOF, and so when you reach:

```
for(i=0; i< numlines; i++)
            fscanf(infile, " %G\t%G", &entry[0][i], &entry[1][i]);
```

every fscanf returns EOF and you don't scan in the values at all.

Answer (score 0):

Keith pointed out *the* problem, but some other things you should think about:

- Check the result of `fscanf`; it will return the number of successful conversions and assignments.  If it comes back less than 2, then you're not reading your data correctly;
- You're using the wrong data type in the `malloc` calls for `entry[0]` and `entry[1]`; you should be using `sizeof (float)`, not `sizeof (float *)`.  You can clean things up by writing `entry[0] = malloc(sizeof *entry[0] * size);` -- this way you won't have those kinds of type mismatches.
- Reading a file twice is inefficient and unnecessary; since you're dynamically allocating your arrays anyway, you can extend the sizes of `entry[0]` and `entry[1]` using `realloc` as you're reading the file.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have added the checking arguments returned by `fscanf` as a safety measure. I am not too sure about using `realloc` which is why i didn't use it. I will look it up on how to resize the array as data is read in.